# Are there any Outlook quirks that can cause content to shoot off the page?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I'm creating a simple email, however when I put it through Litmus Outlook seems to throw the page off completely.

I know that Outlook may not look perfect and that there are plenty of things it doesn't like, but I can't for the life of me figure out why it's throwing some parts of the page off to the side and not others (attached).

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know of any quirks that may cause this behaviour?

I've attached a pen in case it helps:
https://codepen.io/rob-wahlberg-beaney/pen/ZEawrXB?editors=1100

```
<body class="body">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" height="100%" class="gwfw">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" align="center" valign="top">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="610" class="ol610 fw">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 0 5px" class="iph">
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600" class="ol600 fw">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <!-- nav --->
                                    <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" class="sb-nav" align="center">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="" e-editable="linkOneUrl" target="_blank" class="sb-nav-item"
                                                    ><span e-editable="linkOne">Link</span></a
                                                >
                                                <img src=" " class="sb-nav-spacer" />
                                                <a href="" e-editable="linkTwoUrl" target="_blank" class="sb-nav-item"
                                                    ><span e-editable="linkTwo">Link</span></a
                                                >
                                                <img src=" " class="sb-nav-spacer" />
                                                <a href="" e-editable="linkThreeUrl" target="_blank" class="sb-nav-item"
                                                    ><span e-editable="linkThree">Link</span></a
                                                >
                                                <img src=" " class="sb-nav-spacer" />
                                                <a href="" e-editable="linkFourUrl" target="_blank" class="sb-nav-item"
                                                    ><span e-editable="linkFour">Link</span></a
                                                >
                                                <img src=" " class="sb-nav-spacer" />
                                                <a href="" e-editable="linkFiveUrl" target="_blank" class="sb-nav-item"
                                                    ><span e-editable="linkFive">Link</span></a
                                                >
                                                <img src=" " class="sb-nav-spacer" />
                                                <a
                                                    href=""
                                                    e-editable="linkSixUrl"
                                                    target="_blank"
                                                    class="sb-nav-item-sale"
                                                    ><span e-editable="linkSix">Link</span></a
                                                >
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table
                                        cellpadding="0"
                                        cellspacing="0"
                                        class="sb-copy-block-container"
                                        align="center"
                                    >
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="sb-copy-block-spacer"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <table
                                                    cellpadding="0"
                                                    cellspacing="0"
                                                    class="sb-copy-block"
                                                    align="center"
                                                >
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="sb-copy-block-urgency" e-editable="label">urgency</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="sb-copy-block-copy-spacer"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="sb-copy-block-heading" e-editable="header">
                                                            heading onto multiple lines
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="sb-copy-block-copy-spacer"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="sb-copy-block-content" e-editable="textOne">
                                                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
                                                            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
                                                            ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="sb-copy-block-copy-spacer"></td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td valign="middle">
                                                                        <img
                                                                            src="https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/423-4236587_grey-bullet-point-icon-hd-png-download.png"
                                                                            width="21"
                                                                        />
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td width="10"></td>
                                                                    <td
                                                                        valign="middle"
                                                                        class="sb-copy-block-bullet"
                                                                        e-editable="bulletOne"
                                                                    >
                                                                        bullet copy goes here
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td height="5" colspan="3"></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td valign="middle">
                                                                        <img
                                                                            src="https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/423-4236587_grey-bullet-point-icon-hd-png-download.png"
                                                                            width="21"
                                                                        />
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td width="10"></td>
                                                                    <td
                                                                        valign="middle"
                                                                        class="sb-copy-block-bullet"
                                                                        e-editable="bulletTwo"
                                                                    >
                                                                        bullet copy goes here
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td height="5" colspan="3"></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td valign="middle">
                                                                        <img
                                                                            src="https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/423-4236587_grey-bullet-point-icon-hd-png-download.png"
                                                                            width="21"
                                                                        />
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td width="10"></td>
                                                                    <td
                                                                        valign="middle"
                                                                        class="sb-copy-block-bullet"
                                                                        e-editable="bulletThree"
                                                                    >
                                                                        bullet copy goes here
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td height="5" colspan="3"></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td valign="middle">
                                                                        <img
                                                                            src="https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/423-4236587_grey-bullet-point-icon-hd-png-download.png"
                                                                            width="21"
                                                                        />
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td width="10"></td>
                                                                    <td
                                                                        valign="middle"
                                                                        class="sb-copy-block-bullet"
                                                                        e-editable="bulletFour"
                                                                    >
                                                                        bullet copy goes here
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td height="5" colspan="3"></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td valign="middle" class="sb-copy-block-bullet">
                                                                        <img
                                                                            src="https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/423-4236587_grey-bullet-point-icon-hd-png-download.png"
                                                                            width="21"
                                                                        />
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td width="10"></td>
                                                                    <td
                                                                        valign="middle"
                                                                        class="sb-copy-block-bullet"
                                                                        e-editable="bulletFive"
                                                                    >
                                                                        bullet copy goes here
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td height="5" colspan="3"></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="sb-copy-block-copy-spacer"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="sb-copy-block-content" e-editable="textTwo">
                                                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
                                                            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
                                                            ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="sb-copy-block-cta-spacer"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td height="45">
                                                            <a href="" e-editable="ctaUrl" class="sb-copy-block-cta">
                                                                <span e-editable="cta">shop now</span>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="sb-copy-block-copy-spacer-lrg"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- image block -->
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="sb-copy-block" align="center">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <table cellpading="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td valign="top">
                                                            <img
                                                                e-editable="imageOne"
                                                                src="https://placedog.net/500/280"
                                                                class="sb-copy-block-img-side-by"
                                                            />
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td width="20"></td>
                                                        <td valign="top">
                                                            <img
                                                                e-editable="imageTwo"
                                                                src="https://placedog.net/500/280"
                                                                class="sb-copy-block-img-side-by"
                                                            />
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- triple block -->
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="sb-copy-block-container">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="sb-copy-block-spacer"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <table
                                                    cellpadding="0"
                                                    cellspacing="0"
                                                    class="sb-copy-block"
                                                    align="center"
                                                >
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="sb-copy-block-urgency" e-editable="label">urgency</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="sb-copy-block-copy-spacer"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="sb-copy-block-heading" e-editable="header">
                                                            heading onto multiple lines
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="sb-copy-block-copy-spacer"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="sb-copy-block-content" e-editable="text">
                                                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
                                                            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
                                                            ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="sb-triple-block-copy-spacer"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <table
                                                                cellpadding="0"
                                                                cellspacing="0"
                                                                class="sb-triple-block-container"
                                                                align="center"
                                                            >
                                                                <!-- start row -->
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <a href="" e-editable="productOneUrl"
                                                                            ><img
                                                                                e-editable="productOneImage"
                                                                                src="https://placedog.net/500/280"
                                                                                class="sb-triple-block-img"
                                                                        /></a>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td width="11"></td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <a href="" e-editable="productTwoUrl"
                                                                            ><img
                                                                                e-editable="productTwoImage"
                                                                                src="https://placedog.net/500/280"
                                                                                class="sb-triple-block-img"
                                                                        /></a>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td width="11"></td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <a href="" e-editable="productThreeUrl"
                                                                            ><img
                                                                                e-editable="productThreeImage"
                                                                                src="https://placedog.net/500/280"
                                                                                class="sb-triple-block-img"
                                                                        /></a>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td colspan="5" height="7"></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <!-- end row -->
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="sb-copy-block-cta-spacer"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td height="45">
                                                            <a href="" class="sb-copy-block-cta" e-editable="ctaUrl">
                                                                <span e-editable="cta">shop now</span>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="sb-triple-block-copy-spacer"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- end triple block -->
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the same thing as you do on Email on Acid (https://app.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/RJ9v3Ndj1htJxHis6RwMRgYIH5KzlLjo6AiPEX9Fri6wt/list). Also the CodePen you shared and the code you posted are different (there are no styles in the code shared in your post). Can you share the exact same full code you're testing with in Litmus?

Answer (score 0):

One of the biggest things you need is a width attribute on the `<img>` tag. Outlook needs this to work out how large the image should be. If you leave it, it will push the layout out, if the image is larger than the available space.

Use this for example if you want it at 233 width (2 column width):

```
<img e-editable="imageOne" width="233" src="https://placedog.net/500/280" class="sb-copy-block-img-side-by">
```

We could help further if you resolved HTeuMeuLeu's comment.